# Implementing rollback transaction in WP7

Tags: linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7.1

How I can implement rollback transaction in wp7. Presently my issue is after insertion or deletion I am calling submits changes, In that time if i made a tombstone the app exits. how I can handle this situation I am planning to use try catch and if any exception caught means I need to rollback the changes. Please anyone help me to implement the same in wp7.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to rollback when the application becomes tombstoned? Technically your application is not aware of when it is tombstoned, you are only aware of when it becomes de-activated. See the following lifecycle diagram:

[image]

(The image above is from the blog post http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/10/a-windows-phone-7-1-mango-mvvm-tombstoning-example/ which describes the lifecycle in detail)

Whenever you application is de-activated, you can handle the Deactivated event. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.deactivated%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

> Applications are given 10 seconds to complete the Deactivated handler

This gives you the oppurtunity to cleanup, save state and perform other activities before your application becomes de-activated.

I presume you are commiting your transaction when your application state changes? Does the commit run on the UI thread? i.e. is it blocking? If so, you do not need to do anything else (other than ensure it does not take more than 10 seconds). If your commit is running on a background thread, you will have to ensure that your Deactivated event handler blocks until the commit is complete.